# Azure Database : Wrong Time Zone

Tags: azure

Where on Azure can I set my time zone right ?
My datetime trigger as a result does not give me local time right.
I am 2 hours backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/27/lesson-learned-4-modifying-the-default-time-zone-for-your-local-time-zone/

> Currently, the default time zone on Azure SQL DB is UTC. Unfortunately, there is not possible to change by server configuration or database configuration.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can now set the timezone upon creation but there is not an option to change it after that.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-timezone

This is still in public preview though: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/managed-instance-time-zone-preview/

Comment: +1 from me, with a note that you *shouldn't* use anything other than UTC. It's better to store everything in UTC (avoids all sorts of troubles around things like daylight savings leading to uncertainty and repeated times on certain dates).

Comment: @ceejayoz does that comment hold true using a datetimeoffset field?

Comment: I think this was added for app compatibility/interop: "to meet the needs of existing applications that store date and time values and call date and time functions with an implicit context of a specific time zone.". There's nothing wrong with having a db set to a specific time zone, or an offset or time zone specific column (provided it has the offset or is named appropriately), but it's always a good idea to also have data-independent UTC column as well (RecordAddedUTC or EventCreatedUTC or something like that).

Comment: This is only for managed instances, you still can't choose or change timezone for "SQL Database"... Managed Instances and SQL Database are 2 different things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE app setting. Please refer to the following link:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#set-the-time-zone

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL databases are set to UTC timezone with no option to change them.

Comment: @suchit-choudury This is referring to SQL Azure. Kudu supports AppServices, not databases.